# JavaFX on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have JavaFX code that I know that works, but I'm not sure how to run it in Eclipse.

I installed E(fx)clipse and I know that my java files work.

When I try to run the file though it says editor does not contain a main type.

Comment: I've had this same problem as well; I'm interested to see the solution.

Comment: I know that it's something to do with JavaFX not being integrated with Eclipse like it is in Netbeans.

Comment: Not sure if this worked in 2015, but now the answer gives me the same "does not contain a main type error" as when using `Application.launch(TheClass.class)` in a separate class. If I put just a system out into the `main`, then it is found (in Eclipse), and it also works flawlessly when started from the terminal. Using Java FX dependencies via Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the Eclipse workaround for starting JavaFX applications. Simply add the following to the class which extends `javafx.application.Application`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}
```